# How do I ensure the alignment with the currency for small displays?

Tags: css, woocommerce

Can someone help with this issue:

The currency is placed a line above the actual number (price) that is displayed.
It only appears when the window is small (like on a mobile phone). Else it displayed how it should: €44,95 => the currency directly next to the number.

Current code:

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
  44,95
</span>
```

What code can I add to make sure that the currency remains on the same line as the number when the screen width is decreased?

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML structure?

Comment: Yes, I can edit it in the child theme. Or a CSS adjustments is also possible

Comment: Ok then can you post the demo of that page? or the output as a code snippet?

Comment: An example of the page is: https://goldenshop.be/product/golds-gym-pull-over-embossed-hoodie/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the span has `display: block` so the span acts like a block level element occupying the entire line. Try a different value like `display: inline-block` or `display: inline-flex`

```css
.woocommerce.single.single-product .entry-summary .price span {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Screenshot in mobile view.

[image]

Comment: Try installing custom CSS plugin and then use the code.